# Need help to split in Java

Tags: java, string

I have this problem in java. When I write 3/5 + 3 it returns 18/5 and it's correct but if I write 3/5/ + 3 it returns 18/5 instead of error

```
    public static RatNum parse(String s) {
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;
    String split[] = s.split("/");
    if (split.length == 2) {
        x = Integer.parseInt(split[0]);
        y = Integer.parseInt(split[1]);
        return new RatNum(x, y);
    } else if (split.length == 1) {
        x = Integer.parseInt(s);
        return new RatNum(x);
    } else {
        throw new NumberFormatException("Error");
    }
}
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: I don't see how this could work, you're not handling the +.

Comment: What is the string you feed into the function? Just "3/5" and "3/5/", or the whole "3/5 + 3"? The latter seems improbable, because it would crash on parseInt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the regex parser prunes empty entries:
`"3/5/".split("/").length` will return 2.

You can avoid empty entries by making sure it does not start or end with "/":

```
while (s.startsWith("/"))
  s = s.substring(1);

while (s.endsWith("/"))
  s = s.substring(0, s.length()-1);
```

Or throw an error if there is an empty entry:

```
if (s.startsWith("/") || s.endsWith("/"))
   throw new SomeError();
```

Comment: See the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String))